# Is this narration also authentic for the morning?

Tags: authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, dhikr

<sup>I know that there are narrations to recite **أَعُوْذُ بِكَلِمَاتِ اللهِ التَّامَّاتِ مِنْ شَرِّ مَا خَلَقَ** (A'udhu bikalimatil-lahit-tam-mati min sharri ma khalaq) [once](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2708b) or [three](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3604b) times.</sup>

But I have found further narrations that mention ***morning*** as well, which are recorded in Musnad Abu Ya'la ([6688](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32852/6706#p1)) and the other is in Mu'jam al-Awsat ([523](https://al-maktaba.org/book/28171/528)) from At-Tabarani (*See also: Majma'uz-Zawaid ([10/120](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33855/3181)) or Sharhul Adhkar (3/95))*.

I also found that Imam Suyuti mentioned this Dhikr in Da'il Falah ([14-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZqSa.png)) to recite it in the morning and evening three times.

The question is, is the morning part (three times) weak or authentic (with brief comment of a scholar), since I mainly learned about this narration mentioning only evening?

<sup>If found this on [this](https://hadithanswers.com/reference-for-a-dua-to-be-recited-in-the-mornings/) page.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the hadith in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2708b) has two parts:

> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying: When any one of you stays at a place, he should say:" I seek refuge in the Perfect Word of Allah from the evil of that He created." Nothing would then do him any harm until he moves from that place.

which was reported on the authority of Khawla bint Hakim as-Sulamiyyah and was also compiled in [al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/517800).
This statement already should clarify that saying this du'a is not limited to a timing.

> Abu Huraira reported that a person came to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and said:" Allah's Messenger, I was stung by a scorpion during the night. Thereupon he said: Had you recited these words in the evening:" I seek refuge in the Perfect Word of Allah from the evil of what He created," it would not have done any harm to you.

Therefore one could say these words at any time of the day at least once (this was compiled by abu Dawod, at-Tirmidhi and ibn Majah beside a lengthy and somewhat strange version in Musnad Ahmad and in other sources which was discussed in the fatwa on islamweb #[395182](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/395182/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%A8%D9%80-%D8%A3%D9%8E%D8%B9%D9%8F%D9%88%D8%B0%D9%8F-%D8%A8%D9%90%D9%83%D9%8E%D9%84%D9%90%D9%85%D9%8E%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%90-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%D9%90-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%91%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%91%D9%8E%D8%A9%D9%90-%D9%85%D9%90%D9%86%D9%92-%D8%B4%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%91%D9%90-%D9%85%D9%8E%D8%A7-%D8%AE%D9%8E%D9%84%D9%8E%D9%82%D9%8E%D8%8C-%D9%88%D9%8E%D8%B0%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%8E%D8%A3%D9%8E-%D8%B5%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%8B%D8%A7-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A1)). The hadith doesn't set a limit for repetitions.
**Note** that the hadith of Muslim above is the second version of the hadith (so it is a backup evidence of the [Sahih hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2708a)). If al-Bukhari and Muslim repeat a hadith in the same chapter the first quote is that of higher quality and confidence and the more you go on the less quality is in either the chain or content, but still their conditions of sahih are met).

Therefore it doesn't seem to me much beneficial to check all sources of the hadith and their validity or quality.

Saying them trice in the evening has further a strong evidence (which was reported by at-Tirmdihi in his Jami') .
Abu Ya'ala al-Mosily confirmed it for the evening without quoting an amount in report with a sahih sanad and add that it can be said in the morning and evening in a marfo' narration based on an-Narration with the same chain with an addition of rafa' which was reported via 'Ubayd Allah.

The fatwa mentioned above says there's no harm to recite this du'a in the evening or morning. It further said that it was also mentioned in the book of ibn as-Sunni, that of ibn abi Shaybah and al-Haythami in Ghayat al-Maqsid.

**Only at-Tabarani (so far my search results) compiled a version mentioning morning and evening**

This verison is on the authority of abu Hurairah and mentioned in his [al-Awsat](https://al-maktaba.org/book/28171/528):

> 523 - حدثنا أحمد بن القاسم قال: نا محمد بن إبراهيم، أخو أبي معمر قال: نا إبراهيم بن أبي بكر بن المنكدر، عن سهيل، عن أبيه، عن **أبي هريرة** قال: قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: «من قال حين يصبح وحين يمسي: أعوذ بكلمات الله التامات من شر ما خلق، لم يضره شيء»

At-Tabarani also mentioned several other versions and commented on that of the tree times as reported by at-Tirmidhi, which he compiled based on similar chain of transmission #[6038](https://al-maktaba.org/book/28171/6339) saying:

> لم يرو هذا الحديث عن حماد بن زيد مجودا، عن أبى هريرة إلا محمد بن سليمان " ورواه الناس عن حماد، عن سهيل، عن أبيه، عن رجل من أصحاب النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم
> None except Muhammad ibn Sulayman reported this hadith via Hammad ibn Zayd in a correct <sup>(good? free from mistakes?)</sup> manner. But people reported it from Hammad from Suhayl from his father from a man from among the Sahabah

At-Tirmidhi reported it via Yahya ibn Musa, from Yazid ibn Haroon, from Hisham ibn Hassaan, from Suhayl from his father from abu Hurairah.

While at-Tabarani reported it via:
Ahmad ibn al-Qassim [أحمد بن القاسم](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/9663/%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%B1) (trustworthy),
from Muhammad ibn Ibraheem the brother of abu Ma'amar [محمد بن إبراهيم، أخو أبي معمر](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/51411/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A5%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%8A%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86) (Sadooq),
from Ibraheem ibn abu Bakr ibn al-Munkadir [إبراهيم بن أبي بكر بن المنكدر](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/11276/%D8%A5%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%8A%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D9%83%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D9%83%D8%AF%D8%B1) (acceptable, ad-Daraqotni regarded him as da'if),
from Suhail ibn Dhakwaan [سهيل](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/3687/%D8%B3%D9%87%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%B0%D9%83%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86) (trustworthy, had some mistakes),
his father Dhakwaawn [ذكوان](http://hadith.islam-db.com/narrators/2840/%D8%B0%D9%83%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86) also known as abu Salih as-Samman (trustworthy) -> abu Hurairah.

Comment: The first two ahadith are general ones, but my issue is related to the topic for the morning and evening. And the ahadith mention once and three times for the evening. But I wanted to know if there is a specific number for the morning and its authenticity, since Abu Ya‘la mentions it in a general sense (assuming that the number of utterance is **once**). But scholars also specified "***three***" for the morning, therefore I wanted to know if there is a specific hadith for that case and its authenticity.

Comment: Honestly I'd say I don't see benefit in this knowledge. Because the most sahih hadith telling us about this dhikr give us a plenty hand to repeat it when we like and to the amount we like searching for a restriction is causing an unnecessary hardship. So all we can safely say that the 3 times in the evening is also approved as sahih, but even saying less or more wouldn't harm us. Du'a and dhikr is part of what is called salih al-'A'amaal and there's agreement that even da'if hadith in this context can be followed as long as this weakness is not too strong or due to a supposed fabrication.

Comment: Interestingly, I have found the 5 pages of Imam Suyuti‘s book Dail Falah where this Dhikr is mentioned (and edited them into my question), but unfortunately I can not understand Arabic. And since the page claims that Imam Suyuti referenced a narration which would specifiy the mentioning of ***three***, I think it would be intriguing to investigate which hadith he would refer to and what its authenticity of the chain of narrator is.

Comment: @harmer97 if you could provide the preceding page we may or may not learn which source as-Suyuti is referring to as in the commentary it refers to the hadith from Musnad abu Ya'ala which is quoting evening. The only one who quotes both evening and morning and three times in the comment is apparently at-Tabarani.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/VoruFNj.png

Comment: @harmer97 unless the  versions of at-Tabarani or that which the commentator claims to be in ibn 'Ady's al-Kamil (which doesn't confirm it) say otherwise it rather looks like a mistake of as-Suyuti. As all what he quoted says otherwise.

Comment: https://al-maktaba.org/book/12579 this is the book and I have searched through it, and could not find anything related to that. This book is described as: "Al-Kamil fi Dhu'afaa al-Rijaal is one of the oldest and most important collections of low narrators in the Hadith [...] praised by the great Muhaddith Ad-Daraqutni who saw it as sufficient, or Ibn Kathir who will say it was unprecedented." So, that this book would provide an authentic basis for that is unlikely.

Comment: @harmer97 I know the hadith in sl-Kamil is the same as that of abu Ya'ala, mx answer was updated only at-Tabarani could provide such a statement I've even left a rough grading of the narrators.

Comment: These are the ahadith: https://al-maktaba.org/book/12987/219 | https://al-maktaba.org/book/29120/462 | https://al-maktaba.org/book/30479/16 | At #23149: https://al-maktaba.org/book/1438/10136 -> extracted references - quoting: Abu Yusuf Al-Ansari in Kitab Al-Athar (1/41 - 214), and Abu Naim in the Musnad of Abu Hanifa (1/257 - 9) - the question is: Are these references authentic?

Comment: @harmer97 the chain from abu Yusuf's al-Athaar is fine however the statement "فيما أحسب" expresses some doubt of one of the narrators apparently abu Yusuf. The chain of abu Hanifa's al-Musnad is the same (but no doubt expressed here). The chain in the book of al-Khil'iy starts with the same narrators too, but checking the rest is much uneasier, because the chain has much more narrators most of them are only acceptable. As for the book of as-Suyuti it is only pointing at references and gives no further input/information.